# Magento 2: how to add an admin AJAX tab

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, ajax, magento-2.0, tabs

In Magento 1, you can add AJAX tabs by doing the following:

In your `Tabs.php` block:

```
$this->addTab('test_tab', array(
        'label'     => "Test",
        'title'     => "Test",
        'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/test', array('_current' => true)),
        'class'     => 'ajax'
    ));
```

Then in your controller you could do:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And finally in your layout file you had to do:

```
<adminhtml_controller_test>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="module/adminhtml_edit_tab_test" name="module.edit.tab.test"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_controller_test>
```

How to achieve the same thing in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Magento 2, it's slightly different but quite similar.

First in your `Tabs.php` block you still can call the `addTab` method:

```
$this->addTab(
    'test_tab',
    [
        'label' => __('Test'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('adminhtml/*/test', ['_current' => true]),
        'class' => 'ajax'
    ]
);
```

Then you will have to define an action class corresponding to your URL that use a `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Controller;

class Test extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

Finally in your `view/adminhtml/layout/module_controller_test.xml` you need to do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Test" name="module.edit.tab.test"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```